# iphone 6 plus scaling webpage in UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

We have a website that our client uses which looks fine on iOS8 and iPhone 6/6 plus.

We wanted to display it in app in a UIWebView but noticed it was being zoomed.

We use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Should we also set @media

iPhone 5 and below Breakpoint:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) { … }
```

iPhone 6 Breakpoint:

```
@media (min-width: 375px) { … }
```

iPhone 6 Plus Breakpoint:

```
@media (min-width: 414px) { … }
```

We tried checking scaledPageToFit on UIWebView in storyboard but it seems to have no effect.

See screenshot for the problem

Any ideas.

[image]

Comment: Did you set all the launch images of your app ? The app as a whole would be upscaled on the new devices if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like rdurand said, you need to add launch images to your iPhone project. You can either specify a Launch screen file or a launch image source. Once you do that, then your app will not look scaled up or zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

Can be fixed by setting up the iPhone 6/6 plus launch images.

Id also recommend using ASSET CATALOG CREATOR -

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/asset-catalog-creator-app/id809625456?mt=12

Run it twice for IOS ICONS/ IOS SPLASH

then just drag the *xassets files into your project and replace the current only.

HERES how to check if app is zooming:

[image]

[image]